# Is it possible in Commcare to see saved reports made in a different web user account?

Tags: commcare

A partner is having problems with receiving the weekly scheduled reports into their email.

The reports were saved into a different web user account and I can't visualize the settings of the reports and review if there is bug associated with the report or it is a simple configuration issue.

Is there anyway to review remotely the scheduled reports coming out of a different web user account?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Yes, you can view scheduled reports by going to https://www.commcarehq.org/a/YOUR_DOMAIN/reports/saved/ and clicking the "My Scheduled Reports" tab. There you should see a list of scheduled reports. Next to each one is a button that says "View". If you click that, it will preview what the report looks like.</s>

^^ The above only works for your own Scheduled Reports.

#### Edit

There is no way to view other people's scheduled reports. However, you can have them add you to their saved report as a recipient so you can at least see the output.

Comment: I think Juan is saying that when he does this, he can see only the scheduled reports that he configured; if someone else configured the report, he cannot see it. Do you believe that to be true / does this answer take that into account?

Comment: Ah, you are correct. My answer doesn't work for that